# Ant with Proguard - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, ant, proguard

During the build process I get this warning:

```
can't find referenced class com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
```

If I add the library to proguard.cfg with the option -libraryjars (as suggested):

```
-libraryjars path-to/gson-1.7.1.jar
```

the warning goes away BUT when I run the app I get an exception at runtime:

```
...caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you got any solution for this ? I am using Maven and added the Gson dependency in pom.xml but getting same error at runtime

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it available to Ant for the build process.  Try adding that JAR to the Ant /lib directory and rerun your Ant build again.

If you're getting it at runtime, it means that the JAR isn't available to the class loader.

Comment: Sorry @duffymo I have mistakenly edit your answer. How can I revert it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse then open project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs (add the downloaded gson jar). Then close your emulator and start it again.